# Code-injection in non-stored inputs

Tags: security, web, code-injection

Is it possible to have any kind of code-injection for inputs that are not stored into the database?

I have a web application with multiple inputs, but all the inputs are used to filter the "search". So, should I worry about code-injection? If yes, is there any practical example of injection without the input being stored into the database?

Comment: You might call it cross site scripting rather than injection, but yes.

Comment: What code do you hope to inject? Depending on how the search filter is implemented, code injection might work there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is called [Reflected Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Reflected_.28non-persistent.29) (XSS).

You need to validate all inputs always against XSS. No exceptions.

IE 8+ and Chrome 4+ offer some protection against this. You can set the following header to enable this feature:

`X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`

Details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-iv-the-xss-filter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many types of [code injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection) attacks, depending on the technology stack used in your application. Usually properly escaping before using data or stripping characters with special meaning is the way to go. Check any API documentation for security concerns.

[Reflected XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) is one - this is where the code executes in the browser of the user an attacker has managed to get to visit your site (e.g. by sending them a link  to your site also containing some script in the link). However, the primary focus of securing your application is to properly output encode rather than validate input. See the [OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for guidance, however essentially you need to convert characters such as `&` to `&amp;` when output to HTML. Properly output encoding means that the script it displayed rather executed.